# Unexpected value 'DoughnutChartComponent in doughnutChart.component.d.ts' declared by the module 'app.module.ts'

Tags: angular

I am using the [Angular D3 Charts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-d3-charts) while using **ng build --prod**, I am getting the error in the console

> Unexpected value 'DoughnutChartComponent in
>   E:/angular/node_modules/angular-d3-charts/bundle/doughnutChart.component.d.ts'
>   declared by the module 'AppModule in
>   E:/angular/src/app/app.module.ts'. Please add a
>   @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.

But the application is executing with no error in the console while using **ng s --open**

I am using the  **"angular-d3-charts": "^5.0.0"** version of the angular-d3-charts.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './access/login/login.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AccessComponent } from './access/access.component';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
import { AccountComponent } from './account/account.component';
import { NgMultiSelectDropDownModule } from 'ng-multiselect-dropdown';
import {Auth} from './auth.service';
import {RlTagInputModule} from 'angular2-tag-input';

import {Ng2Webstorage} from 'ngx-webstorage';
import { DataTablesModule } from 'angular-datatables';
import { UploadFileService } from './upload-file.service';
import {SharedModule} from './account/shared.module';
import { Daterangepicker } from './daterangepicker/daterangepicker.module';
import {ToasterModule, ToasterService} from 'angular2-toaster';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MultiselectDropdownModule } from 'angular-2-dropdown-multiselect';
import { LeafletModule } from '@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet';
//import {TooltipModule} from "ngx-tooltip";
import {TooltipModule} from 'ng2-tooltip-directive';
import {PopoverModule} from "ngx-popover";
import { RecaptchaModule, RECAPTCHA_SETTINGS, RecaptchaSettings } from 'ng-recaptcha';
import { RecaptchaFormsModule } from 'ng-recaptcha/forms';
import { MixpanelService } from './mixpanel.service';
import { ReportsComponent } from './account/reports/reports.component';
import {DataTableModule} from "angular-6-datatable";
import { DashboardComponent } from './account/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { ListManagementComponent } from './account/list-management/list-management.component';
import { SegmentManagementComponent } from './account/segment-management/segment-management.component';
import { CampignManagementComponent } from './account/campign-management/campign-management.component';
import { TemplateManagementComponent } from './account/template-management/template-management.component';
import { DoughnutChartComponent, PieChartComponent, BarChartComponent } from 'angular-d3-charts';
//import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    AccessComponent,
    AccountComponent,
    ReportsComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    ListManagementComponent,
    SegmentManagementComponent,
    CampignManagementComponent,
    TemplateManagementComponent,
    DoughnutChartComponent, 
    PieChartComponent, 
    BarChartComponent,    

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,    
    RlTagInputModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    Ng2Webstorage,
    DataTablesModule,
    SharedModule,
    Daterangepicker,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ToasterModule.forRoot(),
    LeafletModule.forRoot(),
    NgMultiSelectDropDownModule.forRoot(),
    MultiselectDropdownModule,
    TooltipModule,
    PopoverModule,
    RecaptchaFormsModule,
    RecaptchaModule,
    DataTableModule,
    //ChartsModule
  ],
  providers: [CookieService,MixpanelService,Auth,UploadFileService,{
    provide: RECAPTCHA_SETTINGS,
    useValue: {
      siteKey: 'xxxx',
    } as RecaptchaSettings,
  }],

  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**doughnutChart.component.d.ts** *from node_modules\angular-d3-charts\bundle\doughnutChart.component.d.ts*

```
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
export declare class DoughnutChartComponent {
    width: number;
    height: number;
    iconWidth: number;
    iconHeight: number;
    outerRadius: number;
    innerRadius: number;
    data: any;
    centerImage: any;
    spreadSlice: boolean;
    chartID: string;
    middleText: string;
    middleTextColor: string;
    middleTextFontSize: string;
    centerImageEvent: EventEmitter<{}>;
    constructor();
    ngOnInit(): void;
    renderChart(): void;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code of app.module.ts and doughnutChart.component.d.ts?

Comment: updated the question @SunnyParekh